# Jquery get value from a dynamically generated input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to extract the value from a dynamically generated inputbox which is inside a tr tag . But for some reason, I am facing error and I am getting undefined as the value. What could I be doing wrong? I am relatively new to Jquery. So,please I would like to know where I am doing wrong.

index.js

```
       function dynamic_children() {
    $(function () {
        var no = $('#number_children').val()
        $('#id_children-TOTAL_FORMS').val = no

        children_added = $('#children_td_table tr').length
        remaining = 4 - children_added

        //determine if the no of children input are more than those left
        if (no > remaining) {
            //show alert that max children reached
            $('max-children').show()
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('max-children').hide()
            }, 3000);
        } else if (no < children_added) {

            no_to_remove = children_added - no
            for (i = 0; i < no_to_remove; i++) {
                $('#children_td_table').children().last().remove();
            }

        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < remaining && i < no; i++) {
                no_ = i + 1
                $('#children_td_table')
                    .append($('<tr>')
                        .append('<td>' + no_ + '</td>')
                        .append($('<td>')
                            .append($('<input>')
                                .addClass('Input-text')
                                .attr('name', 'children-' + i + '-child_name')
                                .attr('id', 'children-' + i + '-child_name')

                            )



                        )
                        .append($('</td>'))
                        .append($('<td>')
                            .append($('<input>')
                                .addClass('Input-text')
                                .attr('name', 'children-' + i + '-child_dob')
                                .prop('type', 'date')
                                .prop('class', 'children-' + i + '-child_age')
                                .change(function () {
                                    d = new Date($(this).val());
                                    var before = moment($(d, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
                                    var age = moment().diff(d, 'years');
                                    age_id_name = "#" + $(this).attr('class')
                                    $(age_id_name).val(age);
                                })
                            ))
                        .append($('</td>'))
                        .append($('<td>')
                            .append($('<input>')
                                .addClass('Input-text')
                                .attr('id', 'children-' + i + '-child_age')
                                .attr('name', 'child')
                                .prop('type', 'text')
                            ))
                        .append($('</td>'))
                    )
                    .append($('</tr>'))
            }

        }


        //
        // for (var i = 0; i < no && i < 4; i++) {
        //
        //
        //     $("#delete_row").click(function () {
        //         if (i > 1) {
        //             $("#addr" + (i - 1)).html('');
        //             i--;
        //         }
        //     });
        // }
    })
}
```

---

```
function savechildinfo(){
    var numofchildren = $("#number_children").val();
    console.log("CHildrennumber",numofchildren);
    var tr = $("#children_td_table").closest('tr');



    for(var i =0;i<numofchildren;i++){
        var c = "children-"+i+"-child_name";
        var d = tr.find(c).val();

        console.log("childrenname",d);


    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `this` refering to in 4th line ?

Comment: `var c = "children-"+i+"-child_name";` here the `ID` is missing. `var c = "#children-"+i+"-child_name";`.

Comment: @AjAX.:- Still not working.

Comment: You are — not — closing the `tr` and the `td`.

Comment: Is your 1st function which is generating the table working well ? 
I mean are you stuck at generating the dynamic table or only at extracting the values ?

Comment: @DJYadav:- Yes its working fine. Its just that I pasted a snipped of the code.

Comment: @DJYadav:- I am just stuck at extracting the value from the input box which is inside the table.

Comment: In that case, can you please post the HTML code generated of the table structure ?
I think that would be more beneficial. @jassy

Comment: @DJYadav:- Ok I am adding that

Comment: Where you called `savechildinfo` function?

Comment: @DJYadav:- I have added the code.

Comment: I meant can you just run this dyanmic_children in your own environment and paste here just the sample html generated for that table-tr-td structure. Because, If your dynamic function is working well then no need to confuse the reader here and help him to directly jump to the extracting function where the actual problem exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to understand and read you code, but I highlight your issue down below.

First no need to use `closest` just use `$("#children_td_table")` alone for `var tr`. Second you forget to add `#` for `var c` if you want to find it by `ID` so should use `var c = "#children-" + i + "-child_name";`

```js
var i = 1;
var no_ = '123' // just for fix the error


$('#children_td_table')
  .append($('<tr>')
    .append('<td>' + no_ + '</td>')
    .append($('<td>')
      .append($('<input type="text"/>')
        .addClass('Input-text')
        .attr('name', 'children-' + i + '-child_name')
        .attr('id', 'children-' + i + '-child_name')
        .val('test') // remove this later
      ))
    .append('</td>')
    .append('</tr>')
  );

savechildinfo(); // I execute this on load

function savechildinfo() {
  var numofchildren = 2; // just for fix the error
  console.log("CHildrennumber", numofchildren);
  
  var tr = $("#children_td_table");
  // remove closest
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numofchildren; i++) {
    var c = "#children-" + i + "-child_name";
    // -----^ add #
    var d = tr.find("#children-" + i + "-child_name").val();

    console.log("childrenname", d);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="children_td_table"></table>
```